# Office Web Addin - Open or save or load document from specfic location

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I'm working on an Office word web add-in (not VSTO). I have opened a new / existing document from the current system or from a Sharepoint document library and side-loaded my taskpane addin and ribbon menu. Using a ribbon menu control, I should open a document from a sharepoint document library for editing and saving to some other location in Sharepoint. Is it possible in office.js?

1. Shall I open the document using Javascript API (office.js)?
2. If Point 1 is possible then can I open document from Sharepoint or one drive?
3. Can I save document using office.js to specific location?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried:

1. using the [graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/index) to access the files you need out of One Drive.
2. use the c[ontext.application.createDocument](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/application)().open() API to open the file in Word.
3. Finally, after user updates,  use the [getFileAsync](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/document.getfileasync)() method to get the base64 encoded docx and upload it back to one drive or wherever you need to?

Comment: How can i open docx from Sharepoint or One Drive using Graph?. I dont  know how to use that also am not getting much in internet.

Comment: try https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/onedrive

Comment: btw here is a sample showing how to use the graph from an add-in, its for PPT, but you can use the same principles for Excel.  https://github.com/OfficeDev/PowerPoint-Add-in-Microsoft-Graph-ASPNET-InsertChart